# How to make the children resize along the parent div while maintaining ratio?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

How can I make the child elements resize along the parent elements fluidly while maintaining ratio?

As you can see on the attached video file `aspect-ratio: 1/0` works but when you hover the HTML element, it becomes smaller than the rest of the elements. I want my Hero component to stay within the HTML element with the same effect .How can I fix this?

Video: (The sudden change of the carousel you see is when I changed `width: 1250px` to `max-width: 1250px`)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14l7UzzRDMfd9AVykaF5gvza68HLycfSH/view?usp=sharing

Hero.js (main)

```
<div className="Hero" id="Hero">
    <Accordion />
    <div className="border"></div>
    <Carousel />
</div>
```

Hero.css

```
.Hero {
    width: 1250px;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}

.Hero .border {
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #b3b3b3;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

/* Responsiveness */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
    .Hero {
        aspect-ratio: 1/0;
    }
}
```

I tried changing `width: 1250px` to `max-width: 1250px` and the Hero component stays inside the HTML element. However, resizing it even more smaller makes the Carousel resize instead of the entire Hero component.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).